# Catch a query string with parameter values from a SqlDataSource in ASP.net applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string, sqldatasource

In my ASP.net application I have an `SqlDataSource` with parameters e. g.:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="..." 
    onselecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [SomeTable] WHERE ([SomeTableID] = @SomeTableID)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="SomeTableID" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

For debugging purposes it would be very helpful to somehow catch the query string which is executed on the database server i. e. the query string with filled in parameter values.

I tried to do this in the `SqlDataSource1_Selecting` event, but the `SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs` arguments still contain the `SelectCommand` text as above: `SELECT * FROM [SomeTable] WHERE ([SomeTableID] = @SomeTableID)`.

How can I get the true query string with all @Valiables replaced by the values which are used for the selection?

Comment: Did you try `SelectCommand.Parameters`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I tried `SelectCommand.Parameters` and I could get the values one by one there. But if you have a very long query with many parameters this is quite annoying.

Answer (score 0):

There is **no way** to view it in code.   The SqlCommand class calls sp_execute  which separates the query from the parameters. You'll need to use **Sql Profiler** to see the exact query executed.

You can learn how to use SqlProfiler through [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650699.aspx).